# dynamically updating contents from the results of the cloud api using angular js

Tags: angularjs

i am using angular js, bootstrap thumbnail and google cloud endpoints for my app.

The .html looks part looks like:

```
<body ng-controller="SearchController as searchCtrl">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" ng-repeat="result in searchCtrl.searchResults">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img ng-src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The .js looks like below

```
(function(){
    var app =  angular.module('InstaMonitorAdmin', []);
    app.controller('SearchController', function(){
        this.searchResults = {};

        this.searchTags = function(keyword){
            //this.searchResults = results;

            gapi.client.instagramApi.searchTags({'keyword':keyword}).execute(function(resp) {
                 if(resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                     // error
                     alert(resp.error.message);
                  }else{

                      var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(resp.items);
                      this.searchResults = myJsonString;
                      console.log(myJsonString);
                  } 
            });
        };
    });
```

In the console debugger it shows data for myJsonString as:

```
{"userName":"vikceo",
"caption":"#sandsculpture #sandcastle",
"tags":"[mountains, breathtaking, love, skyporn, minion]",
"thumbnailUrl":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/13108860_653673808116072_1235622514_n.jpg",
"kind":"instagramApi#resourcesItem"},

{"userName":"neetipari","caption":"My love #passion",
"tags":"[weddingcake, love, fondantcakes, foodporn]",
"thumbnailUrl":"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12940136_423862367814317_252510398_n.jpg",
"kind":"instagramApi#resourcesItem”}]
```

The issue is that the page does not render the search results returned from the google end point. I have tested that it return the results fine.

if i comment it and uncomment the top line where i am passing a hard coded array then it works fine.

Is it because it takes more time for response to come and assign to array? I thought it will continue to listen to this array. Please advise

Comment: when did you run the `searchTags` function ? did the log `console.log(resp.items);` display the good data ?

Comment: above it there is a search box <form role="form" ng-submit="searchCtrl.searchTags(searchCtrl.tags)">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a tag to search" ng-model="searchCtrl.tags">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value = "Go!"/>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </form>

Answer (score 1):

so the problem turned out to be how i assigned the returned results. this is the final method:

```
app.controller('SearchController', function(){
        this.searchResults = {};

        this.searchTags = function(keyword){
            var data = this;
            data.searchResults = [];
            gapi.client.instagramApi.searchTags({'keyword':keyword}).execute(function(resp) {
                 if(resp && resp.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                     // error
                     alert(resp.error.message);
                  }else{
                      //successful login
                      console.log(resp);
                      data.searchResults = resp.items;
                  }
                 });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a synchronous assignment to the array , you could wait for the execution such as:

```
gapi.client.instagramApi.searchTags({'keyword':keyword}).execute(function(resp)).then(function(ress) {
      //console.log(ress.items);
      this.searchResults = ress;
 });
```

Comment: this won't even compile

Comment: the parenthesis are not matching it seems

Comment: still has compilation issues

Comment: there was an extra ( after then, removed it

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `ng-if`, if you add `ng-if` element creates after data is come

```
<div ng-if="searchCtrl.searchResults.length" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" ng-repeat="result in searchCtrl.searchResults.items">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img ng-src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working for me. i can see console.log printing the array but page does not render

Comment: just add this searchCtrl.searchResults.length

Comment: can you just print it on your page

Comment: here is what the data looks like on printing console.log(resp)  https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkdnaexi83mqznq/Screenshot%202016-04-27%2000.33.17.png?dl=0

Comment: print it in HTML page like <pre>searchCtrl.searchResults</pre>

Comment: I think the data is in items, searchCtrl.searchResults.items

Comment: it prints {} for that using <pre>...  I added more details to my question see if that helps